# AVD emulator launches but does not load new application

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device, ddms

I'm developing my android app in Eclipse. I used to debug my android app with the AVD emulator and a real phone device as well. Lately I face the following problems when I try to work with the emulator:

When I issue "Run As" or "Debug As" Android Application, the AVD emulator launches but it does not load the latest version of the application. It keeps a previous version of it. The DDMS does not load the "Emulator device" in the Devices tab. Moreover, the Debug "Logcat" does not write anything.

When I work with the phone device everything is working properly. Any suggestions?

Some more info that may help:
From the Manifest file: 
From the default.properties file: target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:12
AVD Emulator targe: Android 3.1 Google APIs Level 12

Comment: delete and install the emulator again or try to clean your project as well as close the project and open it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your emulator properties have `Snapshot` option enabled, then uncheck it and rebuild your application after cleaning it. The emulator might be picking your old copy from snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

in your emulator snapshot should be disabled as well as in "DEV Setting" option USB Debugging mode should be enabled . it will work fine